# Why is json.Unmarshall converting numbers to zero in some cases?

Tags: go, unmarshalling

### Background

I'm trying to analyze data from the Reddit api on users. I've declared a User `struct` like:

```
type User struct {
    Kind string `json:"kind"`
    Data struct {
...
        Subreddit  struct {
        ...
        } `json:"subreddit"`
...
        CreatedUtc        float64     `json:"created_utc"` <---
...
    } `json:"data"`
}
```

I request the data from the api and print it here.

```
func GetUser(url string) User {
    var response User
    resp, err := http.Get(url)

    if err != nil {
        ...
    }

    defer resp.Body.Close()

    body, err := ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body)

    if err != nil {
        ...
    }

    err = json.Unmarshal(body, &response)

    if err != nil {
        ...
    }

    fmt.Print(response.Data.CreatedUtc) <---

    return response
}
```

### Problem

When I request this [endpoint](https://www.reddit.com/user/G-of-all-trades/about.json) it prints 0 while I can see in the browser that the `created_utc` timestamp is 1562538742. This seems to happen in the vast majority (but not all) cases.

Am I doing something wrong with my type conversions?

Comment: Are you certain you're not getting a 429 result or other error? You don't seem to be checking the response code anywhere.

Comment: Your example `User` struct also implies the path to the property would be `response.Data.CreatedUtc`; yet, you've got `response.Data.Data.CreatedUtc`.

Comment: Please show a sample of the JSON you're trying to unmarshal.

Comment: @Gavin I don't think that's correct. Both his model and the real json have only one level of "data".

Comment: Sorry, `response.Data.createdutc` is correct, I missed this when copying my code into SO.

Comment: @JimB I think you are on to something. The status code is 429.

Answer (score -1):

To understand why it is zero, you must first understand that in Go, types are not automatically references like in other languages. The variable `var abc int` will have a value of `0` by default.

When testing whether JSON is parsing correctly, you can change the values of the type to pointers. With this, any field that isn't filled is `nil` rather than the default value for that type.

Doing this, you can see if the value being returned is true, or if there is another failure, such as incorrect data model or failed network call.

Comment: Thanks for the response! That approach makes sense to me. Sorry, I'm pretty new to Go. Can you provide an example for changing the values of the type to pointers?

Comment: Here is an example of the two methods and their default values: https://play.golang.org/p/tezuRn7CbJ2

Answer (score -1):

Credit to @JimB for pointing out that I wasn't checking the status code of the response. I had expected that it would throw an error if it was > 400 but according to the [docs](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Client.Get) that is not the case.

In my case, modifying the request to contain a user agent header resolved the issue.